# Select all vertices connected via an edge and order by edge attribute

Tags: orientdb

I have a 'View' vertex (#74:0) that has 2 (could be more) OUT edges (VertexIncludes) to two 'Item' vertices.

[image]

I want to get these two Item vertices but order them by the VertexIncludes.order attribute (which is an integer).  The image shows these as currently having values of 2 and 3.

The following query will return the edges in the correct order, how do I revise it to get the in attributes that contain the vertex rid?

```
SELECT expand(outE('ViewIncludes')) FROM #74:0 ORDER BY order
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, switch to ArcadeDB.

Then try

```
select inV() from (SELECT expand(outE('ViewIncludes')) FROM #74:0 ORDER BY order)
```

It returns the vertices with arcadedb (but should work with orientDB, too)

Comment: Thank you.  Both for answering the question and for introducing me to ArcadeDB.  Above and beyond.